# Error with static template block tag in Django 1.3

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to use the *static* template block tag in one of my template but I get an exception I don't understand.

Here is the template code:

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}closed.png" alt="Closed message" />
<br/>


{% load static %}
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}closed.png" %}" alt="Closed message"/>
<br/>

<img src="{% static "closed.png" %}" alt="Closed message"/>
```

The two first image display instructions work if I comment out the last one. 
When the last one is uncommented I get an exception:

**Invalid block tag: 'static'**

The code is based on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag) django documentation section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the development version? Most likely, you're using version 1.3, in which case you should be looking at [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag) instead.

Comment: You are right. I'm using 1.3 and not the development version. I found the doc with google and missed the dev in the URL. Thanks. % static % is only in the dev django.

Answer (score 12):

If someone is on > 1.3 and gets this issue, check your INSTALLED_APPS and make sure that `'django.contrib.staticfiles'`, is present. In your template include: `{% load staticfiles %}` and then use it as such:

```
//ensure the your syntax is correct
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static "assets/favicon.ico" %}?v=2" />
```

I ran into this problem because I had a syntax error and verified my setup as per [django projects docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: The 3 steps are Well explained

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, and the problem turned out to be that I forgot to

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

More about it at Django Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Worth adding that this should go in the html file